# Pulsating Dot JQueryUI, animate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a simple, clickable pulsating dot. When clicked, it will move the user to another site. Problem is I can't make animation work, I've tried many examples, animate just simply doesn't work. The dot needs to be fully responsive. I already checked whether JQuery and JQueryUI are working.

Code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">        
          <img id="dot" class="wrapper__dot" src="images/dot.svg" alt="Click to enter site">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    position:relative;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 45%;
    max-height:45%;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    overflow:visible;
}

#dot {
    position:relative;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin-top:-50%;
    margin-left:-50%;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function pulse() {
    $('#dot').animate({
        width: 200, height: 200, 
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 700, function() {
        $('#dot').animate({
            width: 300, height: 300, 
            opacity: 1
        }, 700, function() {
            pulse();
        });
    }); 
};

pulse();

if (typeof jQuery.ui !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('WORKING');
};
```

Comment: Just pasted your code here and it nicely animates: https://jsfiddle.net/8cehs3dc/

Comment: So what exactly are you doing, what are you expecting and what happens?

Comment: I am trying to get this pulse function working. I expect it will animate like you just linked in JSFiddle but on my localhost it just shows SVG image with no animation. It should work like you noticed but my problem is it does'nt, my question is why?

Comment: And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8cehs3dc/1/) is the exact same animation without a single line of JavaScript. jQuery is a thing of the past with CSS3! (Not really. Some bits are, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put it in a comment, but I figure it deserves an answer of its own.

I would question whether jQuery is the right tool for the job. A simple animation like this is a task that can be done with finesse, using jQuery sort of feels like taking a sledgehammer to push a thumbtack into a cork board.

Instead, consider using CSS3 animations. They're very simple to set up, and they are [basically universally supported](http://caniuse.com/css-animation) (a handful of lesser-used browsers still need to play catch-up).

In this case, your CSS is simple:

```css
@keyframes pulse {
    from {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
```

Now that you have defined the animation, apply it to your element:

```css
#box {
    animation: pulse 700ms ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
```

In order, those properties are:

- Animation name: `pulse`
- Animation duration: `700ms`
- Animation interpolation: `ease-in-out` - provides a nice bit of smoothness
- Animation repeat: `infinite`
- Animation direction: `alternate` - animate one way, then back, and so on

The browser will handle the animation natively. This means it will make use of things like its own refresh frames to animate it, which includes bonuses like lowering FPS (often to zero) when the browser tab is hidden to reduce CPU usage and so on. It will animate as smoothly as possible - JavaScript (and jQuery) animations may come close, but will never be quite as smooth.

Regarding browser compatibility (especially older IE)... Is it really worth using that sledgehammer just to provide a little eye candy to people with outdated technology?